# Insert page comment form into a modal

Tags: comment-form

Good day!

How do I insert the comment form of a certain page into a modal? I have in my wordpress website the plugins Popup Maker and Buttonizer. Now I need the comment form to be inserted in the modal. I can seem to find any answers in the web as well as how I can be able to do it.

Thanks in advance.